# Add two sub queries to the query over with Or operator instead of And?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I tried this

```
incidentSubquery.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In (witnessTypesSubquery).
                 WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).NotIn(witnessTypesSubquery);
```

but the operator between the two sub queries is And operator how can I make it or operator instead of and .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be:

```
incidentSubquery.Where
(
  Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<MyEntity>(x => x.Id).In(witnessTypesSubquery))
    .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<MyEntity>(x => x.Id).NotIn(witnessTypesSubquery))
);
```

We can use `Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(...).Add(...)` to join as much as possible OR statements.

Simplified version could be with `Restrictions.Or(A, B)` (just two statements)

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)